# how to have two routes go to same endpoint in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to have two urls be defined on a single line such that

```
http://www.domain.com/share/ig
http://www.domain.com/instagram
```

will redirect to:

```
https://www.instagram.com/igapp
```

I tried something like

```
get ['share/ig','instagram'], to: redirect("https://www.instagram.com/igapp"), as: :share_ig
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Did you try defining it in two different lines?

Comment: y, that works; would prefer on a single line - not sure if it's possible though for the naming of the route etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible with Rails' routes. The `get` method takes a `path` string as the first argument, so it won't recognize an array.

You can sometimes use [dynamic segments](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) to accomplish something similar, but that wouldn't work in this case because your two paths are structured so differently.

If you *really* need to have a one-liner, you can loop over your array and create a path for each.

```
['share/ig','instagram'].each{ |path| get path, to: redirect("https://www.instagram.com/igapp"), as: path }
```